# finding limit value of a given function-real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limits

what does 
$\lim_{n->\infty}$ $\frac{1} {\sqrt{n}}$ $(\frac{1} {\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{3}}$ + .....+$\frac{1} {\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}})$ equals?

1. $\sqrt{2}$
2. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
3. $\sqrt{2}+1$
4. $\frac{1} {\sqrt{2}+1}$
   how do we solve it?

according to me its $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$...

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: Did you do anything to rewrite the limit?

Comment: Hint:$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}-\sqrt{5}}{-2}$

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1} {\sqrt{2k-1}+\sqrt{2k+1}}& =\frac{\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}} {(\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k-1})(\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1})}\\\\
& =\frac{\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}} {(\sqrt{2k+1})^2-(\sqrt{2k-1})^2}
\\\\
& =\frac{\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}} {(2k+1)-(2k-1)}
\\\\
& =\frac{\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}} {2}
\end{align}
$$
Then, summing from $k=1$ to $k=n$, they are telescoping terms: 
$$
\frac{1} {\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{3}} + .....+\frac{1} {\sqrt{2n-1}+\sqrt{2n+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}} {2}-\frac{\sqrt{2\times 1-1}} {2}=\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}} {2}-\frac{1} {2}
$$
and you have to find
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1} {\sqrt{n}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}} {2}-\frac{1} {2}\right)=?
$$
I think you can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution.* Note that the sum inside the parenthesis is $$ \begin {align*} \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {1}{\sqrt{2k+1}+\sqrt{2k-1}} &= \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}}{\left( 2k + 1 \right) - \left( 2k - 1 \right)} \\&= \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac {\sqrt{2k+1}-\sqrt{2k-1}}{2}, \end {align*} $$and notice that this sum [telescopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series) to $ \frac {\sqrt {2n+1} - \sqrt{1}}{2} = \frac {\sqrt{2n+1} - 1}{2} $, so the limit is $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\sqrt{2n+1} - 1}{2\sqrt{n}} = \boxed{\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}, $$which is **option 2**.

Quick recap:

1. Write the general term of the sum and multiply the numerator by the same appropriate quantity to get a nicer form.
2. Notice that the sum telescopes and write the result in terms of $n$.
3. Plug it back in to the original limit and use l'Hoptial's Rule to get the answer.